# Flyback transformer -measurement of average voltage

Tags: transformer, filter, voltage-measurement, buck-boost

Consider buck-boost converter using self-osc. driving, in critical conduction mode, so the duty changes according Vin and Load.

Does measuring the Vx as it is shown between collector and +Vcc, rectifing (consider ideal diode) and averaging using RC filter outputs the same as Load voltage?

I am worry the changed duty corrupt this relation (Vavg vs. Vload).

[image]

The Vx voltage ( plus is collector, minus is +Vcc):

[image]

[image]

Comment: It should be fairly easy to simulate. Have you tried this?

Comment: @Andyaka Well, I didn’t. I am in the phase of “first concept” :)

Comment: Exactly the right time to simulate.